# Does the analytical definition of "closed" include a lack of limit points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, soft-question

I am having difficulty conceptualizing the real analysis definition of "closed" for the case of a set having no limit points.

In *Understanding Analysis*, Stephen Abbott defines a limit point as "a point $x\in A$ so that $x=$ lim $a_n$, given $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $A$ satisfying $a_n\neq x$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. He also defines  a set as "closed" if it contains its limit points.

In general, does the absence of limit points suggest a set contains all of its limit points, or in this case would it be better to show the complement of a set is open?

Comment: Yes, any set with no limits points is closed.  But of course there are also sets with limit points that are closed.

Comment: Yeah, since the set of limit points is empty, and $\varnothing$ is always a subet of every set, it's closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above by Zim, given a set $A$, since the set of limit points is empty and $\emptyset\subset A$, $A$ is closed.